# Mysql cmake and make install error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, mysql, makefile, cmake

I have a problem to install mysql-server(ver.8.0.18).

I think I already had prerequisite packages for install mysql-server on Ubuntu 18.04.

I succeed to cmake, however,I failed on `make install`  and got this error.

> > CMake Error at plugin/x/tests/driver/cmake_install.cmake:47 (file):   file INSTALL cannot find
> >     "/db_prj/mysql-server/bld/runtime_output_directory/mysqlxtest": No
> >     such   file or directory. Call Stack (most recent call first):
> >     plugin/x/tests/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
> >     plugin/x/cmake_install.cmake:78 (include)   cmake_install.cmake:111
> >     (include)

I looked the cmake files, but I can't solve now..

Comment: instead of building on your own, try https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Comment: I know the deb package, but I want to compile my own source. I can't find what the main cause is.

Comment: The error suggests that the file (or directory) does not exist? Did you check if it exists?

Comment: @squareskittles  I downloaded new source file from mysql github.